# EJS "No default engine was specified and no extension was provided" using express router

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm getting a 'No default engine was specified and no extension was provided' on running my app, and I can't understand why.

The setup I've got looks rougly like this:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set view engine
const routes = require('./routes'); // import routes file
app.use('/', routes); // use routes
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'));
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const userRoutes = require('./userRoutes');
const locationRoutes = require('./locationRoutes');

router.use('/users', userRoutes);
router.use('/locations', locationRoutes);

module.exports = router;
```

then there's files like this for users, locations etc:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('users');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I run it, it fails with 'no default engine'. I think I've set this up right, and ejs is definitely installed and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `views` directory as well. Update your code like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path'); //< Add this
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); //< Add this
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Make sure you have a `users.ejs` file in the `views` directory and you should be good.